# PostgreSQL field that changes every 24h

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm in a project where I need to create a random secret unique hash for every user every 24h. The problem is that the table of Users has around 5M rows and I think that a cronjob that updates all the rows in the table is a bit much. My database is a Postgres. Is there a PostgreSQL field that permits this kind of behaviour in an optimal way? Thanks in advance

Comment: A generated column perhaps?

Comment: Like `UPDATE yourtable SET yourhashcolumn = encode(sha256(user_id_column::bytea), 'hex');`? Something like that you run once every 24 hours and let postgres generate the hash for each record and update the column in which you store the hash.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. What you could do here is to generate a [salted hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) including your current date instead of storing to the database a hash that you have to refresh every 24 hours.

For example, in Python3 you could use `hashlib.md5(b"<seed>:<user_id>:<today_date>")` and every day at 00.00 a new unique hash for User X will be re-created.